# Can't render layout in Android Studio 0.8.6 with android-times-square v1.3.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm struggling with the **embedded renderer** in Android Studio of a calendar-picker plugin android-times-square.

https://github.com/square/android-times-square

My layout declaration:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView
    android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    />
```

The relevant exception stack trace being **shown by the IDE:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'L'
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:845)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:659)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:585)
at com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView.<init>(CalendarPickerView.java:121)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

Now, I'm aware of changes in valid character patterns beginning from API version 9 (addition of 'L' and 'C') but I have my SDK's managed by build.gradle in the following way:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.5.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.3.0@aar'
}
```

Therefore there shouldn't be any problem with resolving proper versions and SDK sources with the troublesome 'L' for that matter. Here's the screenshot to the Preview settings:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hPgV.jpg

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess.. Couldn't it be that your previewing in Android L version?

Comment: The basic problem is that the layout preview is using the JDK's version of the SimpleDateFormat class, and not Android's version of it; the Android version doesn't have a `compile()` method at all. Let me investigate.

Comment: After investigating, yes, it's a bug -- not much more I can add at this time. I promoted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time it's a bug in the layout library that the preview renderer uses -- it's calling the JDK version of the `SimpleDateFormat` class instead of the Android version. You can tell this because the Android version doesn't have a `compile()` method at all.

You can track the bug at

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75940

Comment: Yeah, well this is what I presumed at first, that the incorrect SimpleDateFormat is being referenced. Thanks for your input